# CSS button transition linear-gradient background into transparent background

Tags: html, css, linear-gradients

I have a button with a linear-gradient background, orange border, and some text. When I hover over the button, I want the background to become transparent without changing the other properties of the button.

I've tried to transition the opacity to 0, but obviously, this will hide the border and text. I've also tried transitioning the background, but it does not work because I don't have an endpoint to transition to since it needs to be transparent.

```css
body {
    background-color: darkblue;
}

.button {
    background-image: linear-gradient(red,yellow);
    border: solid orange 2px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px 25px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 24px;
}
```

```html
<button class="button">Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a pseudo element for the background and you can easily do this:

```css
body {
  background-color: darkblue;
}

.button {
  border: solid orange 2px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 24px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index:0;
  background:transparent;
}

.button::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-image: linear-gradient(red, yellow);
  transition:1s;
}
.button:hover::before {
  opacity:0;
}
```

```html
<button class="button">Submit</button>
```

Here is another idea without the use of pseudo element where you can rely on changing the `background-color` and `background-size`. The trick is to keep one of the gradient color transparent so we can see the `background-color` (you can have transition on this one to transparent). Then you increase the `background-size` to hide the bottom color and we only see the transparent.

```css
body {
  background-color: darkblue;
}

.button {
  border: solid orange 2px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(transparent, yellow);
  background-size:100% 100%;
  background-color:red;
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 24px;
  transition:1s;
}

.button:hover {
  background-color:transparent;
  background-size:100% 500%;
}
```

```html
<button class="button">Submit</button>
```

---

Or consider adjusting `background-size` to have another kind of transition:

```css
body {
  background-color: darkblue;
}

.button {
  border: solid orange 2px;
  background: 
    linear-gradient(red, yellow),
    transparent;
  background-size:100% 100%;
  background-position:left; /*change this to change the way the transtion happen*/
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 24px;
  transition:1s;
}

.button:hover {
  background-size:0% 100%;
}
```

```html
<button class="button">Submit</button>
```

Comment: The last transition is exactly what I was going to implement after I figured out how to transition to a transparent background, so thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

In Chrome with Experimental Web Platform features enabled ([see](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5640265926705152)) we can use:

```js
CSS.registerProperty({
  name: '--alpha', 
  syntax: '<number>', 
  initialValue: 1, 
  inherits: true,
})
```

```css
body {
  background-color: darkblue;
}

.button {
  --alpha: 1;
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(255,0,0,var(--alpha)), rgba(255,255,0,var(--alpha))) transparent;
  border: solid orange 2px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 24px;
  transition: --alpha 1s linear;
}

.button:hover {
  --alpha: 0;
}
```

```html
<button class="button">Submit</button>
```

> [image]
>
> [image]

Answer (score 1):

Now we can use new [`@property`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@property). See the [support table](https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_at-rules_property).

```css
@property --alpha {
  syntax: '<number>';
  inherits: false;
  initial-value: 1;
}

body {
  background-color: darkblue;
}

.button {
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(255, 0, 0, var(--alpha)), rgba(255, 255, 0, var(--alpha)));
  transition: --alpha 1s;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: solid orange 2px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 24px;
}

.button:hover {
  --alpha: 0;
}
```

```html
<button class="button">Submit</button>
```

Comment: `clearInterval` is missing. And why do you use 2 variables with the same value?

Comment: @Qwertiy updated with new method.

Answer (score -1):

This might help:

```css
body {
    background-color: darkblue;
}

.button {
    background-image: linear-gradient(red,yellow);
    border: solid orange 2px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px 25px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 24px;
    transition: 2s;
    z-index: 1000;
    
}
button:hover{
background:linear-gradient(transparent, transparent);
}
```

```html
<button class="button">Submit</button>
```

So, I just set the hover to a linear gradient of transparent, since you don't have a fixed color.

Comment: there is no transition in your example