# Why CSS.registerProperty is in JavaScript but not in CSS?

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, css-houdini

There is a draft of such feature as [`CSS.registerProperty`](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5640265926705152). In fact, it allows to define types for CSS variables so that browser will be able to extend its abilities about them including animating values.

For me it seems strange that the feature that can be used for CSS-only purposes ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54987010/4928642)) has only JavaScript representation and can't be used from pure CSS.

Is there any reason to include it in JavaScript but not propose same thing for CSS?

---

The things that I can't do from CSS now:

- Specify the type (`syntax`) - without it CSS animation wouldn't work ([the same example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54987010/4928642))
- Specify `inherits: false`

Comment: Isn't `--property: 'value'` is the same? I mean this syntax provides almost the same functionality for CSS as registerProperty - for JS.

Comment: @lucifer63, see my example in other question. Without call to `registerProperty` Chrome does not animate it. So it is required for animation to work. But if user will turn off js, there wouldn't be the call, so animation will be lost. And I don't see reasons why it should work in suach manner.

Comment: @lucifer63, also seems like `inherits` can't be set to `false` from css.

Comment: Yeah, seems like they're not the same, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually [been discussed already](https://github.com/w3c/css-houdini-drafts/issues/137), and if things go right, we should be able to use an `@property` rule.

Current discussions would convert your js to

```css
@property --alpha {
  syntax: "<number>"; 
  initialValue: 1;
  inherits: true;
})
```